# Remove duplicate elements from an unsorted array without using any inbuilt function or without using any other array variable in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi in my first nodejs interview interviewer ask me to remove all duplicate elements from an unsorted array without using any inbuilt function using java script in minimum TC and without using any other array.

This is my efforts.

```js
 var input = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5,2, 6,3,6,1];
var current = input[0];
var found = false;
function removeDuplicate() {
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (current == input[i]) {
            //found = false;
        } else if (current != input[i]) {
            console.log(" " + current);
            current = input[i];
            found = false;
        }
    }
    console.log(" " + current);

}
removeDuplicate();
```

Comment: Is this a question? if so, what's the question?

Comment: Can't be done. You have to use `splice`, `slice` or something similar to modify the array in place, and you have to use `indexOf`, `lastIndexOf` or `includes` to check for dupes, and thet are all native inbuilt array methods.

Comment: @adeneo dont you think that splice, slice or whatever have been made using pure javascript? So i m pretty sure it can be done without using it

Comment: No, those methods are written in C++ or whatever the engine is written in. Not all built-ins can be replicated in JS, escpecially when you can't use other built in methods to do so.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really understand precisely what inbuild functions are or to what extent is a function inbuilt, so I'm assuming I'm not allowed to use `indexOf`, `hasOwnProperty`, `Array.prototype.push`, ...

```js
const input = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5,2, 6,3,6,1];

function removeDuplicate(arr) {
    const result = [];
    let idx = 0;
    const tmp = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!tmp[arr[i]]) {
            tmp[arr[i]] = 1;
            result[idx] = arr[i];
            idx++;
        } 
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(removeDuplicate(input));
```

If you want to remove the elements in place, then the best I can do is save the elements in place, and give the length of the eventual array. But in JavaScript, it's actually valid since arrays in JavaScript are just objects that are enumberable with an extra property `length`.

```js
const input1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5,2, 6,3,6,1];
const input2 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5,2, 6,3,6,7];

function removeDuplicate(arr) {
    let length = 0;
    const tmp = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!tmp[arr[i]]) {
            tmp[arr[i]] = 1;
            arr[length] = arr[i];
            length++;
        }
    }
    
    // the last element is not a duplicate
    if (!tmp[arr[arr.length-1]]) {
        length--;
    }
    arr.length = length;
    return arr;
}

console.log(removeDuplicate(input1));
console.log(removeDuplicate(input2));
```

Comment: Now do that ... *"...and without using any other array"* i.e. modify the array in place !

Comment: @adeneo I just did.

Comment: That's not bad, using an object and rebuilding the array with the duplicates at the end, and then "slicing" it by changing the length.

Comment: @adeneo Too bad that you removed your answer because I think it was the best. :(

Comment: @Manish chauhan would you kindly check this answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

### One line of vanilla JavaScript with no loops

Since this seems like a homework then at least make some effort to make the solution interesting.

This is my first solution but it uses a built-in `.filter()` method:

```
const removeDuplicate = (c=>a=>a.filter(e=>!(c[e]||(c[e]=1)&&0)))({});
```

Here is another solution without using built-ins:

```
const f = (c=>(h,...r)=>h?(c[h]|=0)||c[h]++?f(...r):[h,...f(...r)]:[])({});
const removeDuplicate = a => f(...a);
```

Here you go. One line of vanilla JavaScript plus a convenience wrapper- the second line is so you can use:

```
console.log(removeDuplicate(input));
// or with literals:
console.log(removeDuplicate([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1]));
```

but if you're fine with this:

```
console.log(f(...input));
// or with literals:
console.log(f(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1));
```

then you can remove the second line (and of course rename `f` to something better).

Comment: `Array.filter` is a built-in

Comment: @adeneo You're right. See my updated answer with no built-ins. Additionally I would consider `for` loop to be a built-in and my solution doesn't use it (inlike some other answers here that do).

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arrayB = [
   {id: 1, name: "abc"}, 
   {id:2, name: "abccc"},
   {id: 2, name: "xyz"}, 
   {id:3, name: "abccc"},
   {id: 4, name : "asdada"}
  ];

function findRepeatedObject(arr) {
  var newObj = {};
  var newArr = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (newObj[arr[i].id]) {
      newObj[arr[i].id] += 1;
    } else {
      newObj[arr[i].id] = 1;
      newArr.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
console.log(findRepeatedObject(arrayB));
//output will be [{ id: 1, name: 'abc' },{ id: 2, name: 'abccc' },{ id: 3, name: 'abccc' },{ id: 4, name: 'asdada' }];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr=[
{id: 1, "name": "kumar"}, 
{id: 1, "name": "kumar"}, 
{id: 2, "name": "kumar1"}, 
{id: 2, "name": "kumar1"}, 
{id: 3, "name": "kumar2"}
];
var res=[];
var count={};
arr.forEach((el,ind)=>{
   count[el.id]=(count[el.id] || 0)+1;
   if(count[el.id]<2){
        res.push(el);
   }
})
 console.log(res)//[{ id: 1, name: 'kumar' },{ id: 2, name: 'kumar1' },{ id: 3, name: 'kumar2' }]enter code here
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr =[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5,2, 6,3,6,1];
function removeduplicate(arr) {
  let result = [],k=0,lastoccur;
  for (let i = 0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    for (let j = 0;j<arr.length;j++) {
      if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
        lastoccur = j 
      }
    }
    if (i === lastoccur) { 
      result[k] = arr[i];
      k++;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(removeduplicate(arr));
```